# Customising word separators in vi

Tags: editor, vi

vi treats dash `-` and space   as word separators for commands such as `dw` and `cw`.

Is there a way to add underscore `_` as well?

I quite often want to change part of a variable name containing underscores, such as changing `src_branch` to `dest_branch`. I end up counting characters and using `s` (like `3sdest`), but it would be much easier to use `cw` (like `cwdest`).

Comment: FWIW you can avoid the counting with `ct_dest`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In case you're using vim, you can change that by setting the `iskeyword` option (`:he iskeyword`). If that is not an option, you can always use `ct_` instead of counting.

Comment: Just vi, not vim. Wasn't aware of ct - that will certainly be a help, thanks

Answer (score 45):

> Is there a way to add underscore `_` as well?

```viscript
:set iskeyword-=_
```

What is, and is not a member character to keywords depends on the language.  For help on iskeyword use `:help iskeyword`.

Comment: I was using vi, not vim, so not an option

Comment: Any reason for using vi rather than vim?

Comment: I guess you've never worked in a locked down, highly changed-controlled environment run by paranoid PHBs! :)  i.e. getting vim  installed would have meant a world of pain...

Comment: I quit that job, and you couldn't pay me enough to go back.

Comment: That command works by editing the [`'iskeyword'` option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27iskeyword%27). Its default value on UNIX is `"@,48-57,_,192-255"`, and the [`set-=`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#:set-=) changes it to `"@,48-57,192-255"`.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane. I'll say it again, this is vi, not vim. There is no option to use iskeyword.

Comment: @JoeWatkins I posted that info about `'iskeyword'` not for you, but rather for all the Vim users who are [led here by Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Vim+word+characters).

Comment: @RoryO'Kane And we thank you for it. However, this effectively counts every `_` as its own word. Any way to get it to skip over it as it does whitespace on `w` motion?

Comment: @OllieFord From the docs for [`w`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#w) and [`word`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#word), it doesn’t look like there’s any built-in way. If you want `w` and similar motions to work differently, you’ll have to rebind them to functions provided by a plugin or by you. If you write your own motion, the plugin [vim-textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user) can help you create the equivalent text objects (`iw`, `aw`) too.

Answer (score 6):

One other good option in such cases is to use [camelcasemotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905) plugin.

It adds new motions `,b`, `,e`, and `,w`, which work analogously with `b`, `e`, and `w`, except that they recognize CamelCase and snake_case words.  With it you can use

```
c,edest
```

and this will replace "src_branch" with "dest_branch" if your cursor was on first character of "src_branch".

Answer (score 1):

You could type `cf_dest_` and save the counting part.

**Edit:** or as suggested: `ct_` changes text until right before the underline character. (I'm using the `f` motion more, so it came more naturally to me)

Or you could redefine `'iskeyword'` (`:help iskeyword` for details).

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking at this myself and added this to my .vimrc:

```
set iskeyword=!-~,^*,^45,^124,^34,192-255,^_
```

My .vimrc had issues with ^| and ^", which was part of the default iskeyword for my setup, so I changed to their ascii values and it works fine.  My main modification was to add "^_" to the end of the default setting to keep vim from seeing underscore as being part of a word.

Comment: FYI, removing the underscore from iskeyword can mess up syntax highlighting.  If anyone knows how to get vim to see the underscore as a non-word character for navigation purposes but not for syntax highlighting, let me know.

Comment: You can use a plugin to get this effect, for example, camelcasemotion.

Answer (score -1):

To delete to the next underscore enter "df_"
To change to the next underscore enter "cf_"
NOTE: don't include the double quotes.